# Neo4J jconsole don't show all attributes

Tags: java, neo4j, monitoring, jmx, jconsole

I dont't get all attributes in MBeans -> org.neo4j

Why jconsole don't show me locking transaction and so on?

I have test on server and embedded version but always the same. (Neo4J 1.9.1 & Glassfish 3.1.2)

[image: My jconsole]

[image: Correct jconsole]

Comment: do they show in neo4j-server on the last tab "Server Info"?

Comment: Can't because we use embedded neo4j :/ and last week on tuesday u have show it to us on embedded and i have reviewed my console history and i type the same as u in the console... :o

Comment: Probably difference between enterprise and community? What version had you running last week?

Comment: did you look under "Transaction" second from bottom in your left side of the window

Comment: Last week i had running community 1.9 but know 1.9.1 .... And i cant look at this because i hade no "Transaction" there...

Comment: Only enterprise and advanced version offer the detailed monitoring. For embedded you can use the `neo4j-enterprise` dependencies.